# Why does iPhone 5.1 Simulator give less debugging info than 4.3 Simulator?

Tags: ios, debugging, ios-simulator, crash-reports

Somewhere in my code, I did some mistake by assigning NSNumber to NSString:

```
self.totalLikesLabel.text=[user objectForKey:@"totalLikes"];
```

[image: Comparison of crash information between 5.1 Simulator (top) and 4.3 Simulator (bottom)]

When the app crashes at the point above, 5.1 Simulator did not show specific information of what lines in my code cause the crash. However, 4.3 Simulator did!

Do I have to configure some settings in 5.1 Simulator to have it working like 4.3 in this case?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to phrase it as: "Why does iPhone 5.1 Simulator give less debugging info than 4.3 Simulator?"

Comment: @FabienB Thanks for re-phrasing my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.Go to the breakpoint navigator (left navigation panel 6th one from the left).
2. Click the "+" button at the bottom
3. Select Exception Breakpoint
4. Leave Exception Breakpoint checked
5. In the Exception: field select "Objective-C"
6. In the Break: field select "On Throw"
7. Leave Action: alone (unless you want it to do something)
8. Leave Option: **unchecked**
9. Click "Done"
```

This should let you see a little more than SIGABRT.

Comment: Many thanks. Works like a charm! (Just wondering why this is not the default.)

Answer (score 0):

What do you get with the 5.1 simulator?

To prevent such runtime errors, you could encapsulate that with `@try {} @catch {}` or check the object before assigning:

```
id s = [user objectForKey:@"totalLikes"];

if ([s isKindOfClass [NSString class]]) ...
```

Comment: In short, signal SIGABRT, pointing a line to main.m and -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e5fe70 without pointing anywhere in my code. This is unlike 4.3 Simulator which exactly points to the line I posted in the question.

Comment: I think the point of using debugging information is we don't know where in the code we should use `@try` and `@catch` in the first place.

Comment: Plus, try and catch is resource intensive.